# Why is a sync call on a thread beneficial?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, swift

I have read through several tutorials on the Grand Central Dispatch but I dont understand one thing:

Why dispatch_sync is any faster than not using threading at all? If I have thread 1 waiting for thread 2 to finish, whats the point in even using a second thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you are on a background thread. And let's say you need to do something on the main thread to talk to the interface, but you must not permit the background thread to finish, because the main thread needs some resource from the background thread, like a file. Then it is actually good to use `sync`. It blocks the background thread while you're on the main thread, and you actually *want* to do that.

This is an example from my book:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.swift

Let's say `main` is `false`, so we come into the delegate methods on a background thread. At the end of `didFinishDownloadingToURL`, a file has been downloaded and is waiting to be picked up; we call the caller back on the main thread telling them about it. We *must* use `sync`, because if we don't, our background thread will finish and the downloaded file will be destroyed before the caller has a chance to pick it up.

Comment: So to be clear a sync call isnt faster but does provide variable saftey but an async call is actually faster?

Comment: I didn't say anything about anything being "faster" and I don't see where you're coming from with the whole "faster" thing. Threads are not about "faster". You use a thread other than the main thread because you mustn't block the main thread while any time-consuming thing is going on, that's all.

Comment: Well, it's an overstatement to say threads are **never** about being faster. On a multi-core system, threads make concurrency possible, where you can have the system doing more than one thing at a time. On a system with lots of cores, and where the multiple concurrent tasks don't have any dependencies, you can indeed get the task done much faster.

Comment: @DuncanC Well, sure, Pixar couldn't render a movie in less than 10 years without massive parallel multi-processing. Those are threads, I guess! But I'm talking about iOS, where I'm used to developing for one processor. The newer processors do make things faster, and Cocoa's threading certainly has something to do with it, but _my_ threading doesn't. If I could edit my earlier comment I'd insert "iOS" but I can't. Anyhow, my main goal in that comment was to get the OP to stop barking up the wrong tree, and I still think I was right to try to do that.

Comment: Newer devices (since the 4s, if I'm not mistaken) have 2 or more cores, so my comment about threads making things faster has applied for a long time now.

Comment: Your threading does indeed have something to do with faster performance if you design your app to do things concurrently, and run on a device as new as the iPhone 4s or later.